# Vaadin 10 maven pom file

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin10

I was trying to migrate from Vaadin 8 to 10 and I 'm having issues when i updated the version of the vaadin-bom in my pom file.

previous:

```
<properties>
   <vaadin.version>8.4.3</vaadin.version>
   <vaadin.plugin.version>8.4.3</vaadin.plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Once i update the version to 10.0.1, I already get errors for all dependencies

> Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar is missing.

Do i explicitly place a version for the dependencies (latest is still 8++)? or are there any steps i should change in my pom file to make the update successful?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, try Maven -> Update Project -> select Force update of Snapshots -> Ok. Also, `maven clean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin 10 is packaged in a slightly different way compared to previous versions, which among other things means that there are different artifact ids and a different Maven plugin (which is only needed for production builds). Directly updating simply by changing the version number and resolving compilation errors is not recommended.

You can use one of the "Project Base" starters from https://vaadin.com/start to find a working baseline `pom.xml` setup and then add your own things on top of that.